# How to append to an array content from text files?

Tags: python, django

Can you explain me ,why this code:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers

def getData(request):
    arr = []

    with open('test1.txt') as test1:
        arr.append( test1.read() )
    with open('test2.txt') as test2:
        arr.append( test2.read() )

    serializedData = serializers.serialize('json', arr)

    return JsonResponse(serializedData)
```

Return this warning message ? :

> 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

I just wanna append to an array content from two text  files. That's all

Comment: show the full traceback of the error.

Comment: you mean -?>
AttributeError at /djangoTest/test1

'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/djangoTest/test1
Django Version:  1.10.6
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Exception Location:  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\serializers\base.py in serialize, line 83
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:  2.7.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Django’s serialization framework provides a mechanism for “translating” **Django models** into other formats.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/)

You cannot, and do not need to, use Django serializers on plain objects like lists of strings. `JsonResponse` handles conversion to JSON itself. The only caveat is that you need to pass it a dictionary or you'll get a different error. Something like this:

```
return JsonResponse({'arr': arr})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really all in the [python IO docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

```
arr = []
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as test1:
    for line in test1:
        arr.append(line)
with open('test2.txt', 'r') as test2:
    for line in test2:
        arr.append(line)
```

Comment: Note that this can be done more succinctly, I'm sure, but this is the most basic form/way to 'read from file', and that's why I chose to present it like this.

Comment: `for (l in test2):` is not valid syntax, and neither are the unexpected indents. It's also pretty much always recommended to handle files in a with statement.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer.
But the code returns this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax in this line: for (l in test2):  <- Why ?

Comment: Sorry! I thought I was using the with statements taht Alex was talking about. Fixed now. Note that when copying, you'll have to reapply the tabs yourself, since S.O uses spaces not tabs (which will not play nice with other python code). Thanks @AlexHall for the note.

Comment: Also @python_b this adds them line by line... Is this what you want or do you want the entire strings as two entries? (ie you want `len(arr) == 2` when done?)

Comment: The syntax error is because of the parentheses in your for loop. I removed them. Also never use `l` as a variable name, looks too much like `1` or `I` or `|`.

Comment: @Emad Y I changed my code and at the console I still see the sae error: invalid syntax  for (l in test1):

Comment: Yep, the array will always have only two elements

Comment: @Alex I removed the parentheses  and now I see this message:  'str' object has no attribute '_meta' again